# Can't seem to get ScrollView to work

Tags: android, xml, uiscrollview

So I have surrounded RelativeLayout with ScrollView but when I run it in the Android emulator, it is still not scrolling. Did I accidentally messed up some code? Because it just stopped scrolling.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/new_meal_form_relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/meal_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/meal_label"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/meal_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/meal_label"
            android:hint="Event Title"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/meal_location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/meal_name"
            android:hint="Location(eg: CSC Room232)* "
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/meal_event"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/meal_location"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Description of the event. What kind of food. Any additional info... \n"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/meal_event"
            android:text="Rating: "/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/rating_spinner"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewRequired"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewRating"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRequired"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewRating"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="*Required"

            android:textColor="#ffff4b48"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <com.parse.ParseImageView
            android:id="@+id/meal_preview_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rating_spinner"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/photo_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_photo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/meal_preview_image"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photo_button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:background="#ffff001f"
            android:text="@string/save_button_text"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photo_button"
            android:text="@string/cancel_button_text"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of your relative layout should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. And also why "wrap_content"?